# Mongodb: aggregate with empty condition return null

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a query which is following.

```
module.exports.list = (req, res) => {
  let queryFilter = {};
  let where = {};

  if (req.query.filter) {
    queryFilter = JSON.parse(req.query.filter);
  }

  let pipeLine = [];

  if (queryFilter.lookupcompantype) {
    pipeLine.push({ "$lookup": queryFilter.lookupcompantype });
  }
  if (queryFilter.unwind) {
    pipeLine.push({ "$unwind": queryFilter.unwind });
  }

  if (queryFilter.where) {
    pipeLine.push({ "$match": queryFilter.where });
  }
  if (queryFilter.skip || queryFilter.limit) {
    pipeLine.push({ "$skip": queryFilter.skip });
    pipeLine.push({ "$limit": queryFilter.limit });
  } else if (queryFilter.all) {
    pipeLine.push({ "$count": "total" });
  }

  Company.aggregate(pipeLine)
    .then(list => res.json(list))
    .catch(err => res.json(err));
};
```

It works fine if `pipeLine` is not empty. It returns null if `pipeLine` is empty array `[]`.

I am wondering why?

Becuase if I run the same query with `robomongo` with empty array works fine

```
 MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
 MongoDB server version: 3.6.2
 mongoose : 4.13.9
```

Comment: Not so sure why it's returning null if the pipeline is empty but have you tried pushing an empty `$match` document e.g before running the `aggregate()` check the `pipeLine` length i.e. `if (pipeLine.length === 0) pipeLine.push({ "$match": {}});`?

Comment: Can be attributed to this line https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/aggregate.js#L763 ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the input it's hard to tell but my guess is you're missing the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays`option on unwind. See this example:

```
$unwind: {
  path: '$someArray',
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
},
```

It will preserve the root object if there are no items to unwind in the array.

see:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/